# Is there any way to disable echo of only specified characters on terminal using C?

Tags: c, unix, termios

I know that I can unset `ECHO` flag in `struct termios` to disable echo of all characters, or I can unset `ECHOCTL` flag to disable echo of characters like ^C, ^\ , etc. But I have three questions here:

1. Is there any way to disable only specified characters, like only disable ^\ ?
2. If not, why ^D is not printed anyway, even when `ECHO` and `ECHOCTL` flags are both set?
3. How does bash or other shells handle this? Bash prints ^C, but does not print ^\ .

Comment: Succinctly, no.

Comment: It is better to use `cat` for experimenting rather than `bash` because the latter changes the termios settings dynamically, but `cat` leaves them alone.